# Dynamic animation using storyboards

Tags: wpf, data-binding, animation, mvvm, binding

I develop an application in WPF using the MVVM pattern.
I am displaying an oriented graph, with nodes and links (see following picture).

http://free0.hiboox.com/images/1110/diapo1c36a4b95802846b8553d2fe9b9e6639.png?26

The user can drag and drop the nodes from one "cell" to another. When the user drops a node, its position is changed to align it in the grid. What I want to do, is to animate the node when its position is adjusted during the alignment routine.

The nodes, links and separators are all items displayed in an ItemsControl. Their representation is controlled with some DataTemplates, and their position with Styles.

What I am doing is the following :

```
private void Align() {
    // Computations...
    TX = ... //Target X is set
    TY = ... //target Y is set
    X = TX;
    Y = TY; // X and Y setters fire PropertyChanged
}

<Style x:Key="NodeViewStyle">
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

What I want to do is the following :

```
private void Align() {
    // Computations...
    TX = ...
    TY = ... //TX and TY setters fire PropertyChanged
}

<Style x:Key="NodeViewStyle">
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="UPDATEPOS">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="{Binding TX}" Duration="0:0:1"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

But this does not work at runtime, since I cannot bind to "To" property of my DoubleAnimation (it's a Freezable).

What is the simpliest way of doing such a dynamic animation ? Animating the "X" property through a timer directly in the viewmodel ?

Comment: did you find an MVVM-like solution to this? It would be great if you could post up a little snippet of your xaml code (more specifically the 'To' binding issue) of your solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a similar problem animating an ancillary (attached) property from 0 to 1 and then binding the desired target property to the ancillary one with a value converter. 
Does it makes sense?

Comment: It makes some sense indeed. That's a common workaround for some quite-not-similar issues, since this kind of issue is not very frequent on google or stackoverflow :)

But as a big MVVM fan, I am disapointed to see that I solved the problem much more easily without the pattern. Too much overhead is just too much.

I hope this behavior will be make easier with future framework revisions, like they did with InputGesture beeing a Freezable and not accepting command bindings. Freezables are cool, but not always.